# How to link to internal link with ampersand?

Tags: url, markdown, jekyll, anchor, ampersand

I am trying to make an internal link to a heading called "word & word".
Since I am using Jekyll, the content is in Markdown files and the heading I want to link to looks like this:

```
### word & word
```

I know that I can not use `&` in URLs.
Therefore this would not be an option:

```
#word-&-word
```

I also tried:

```
#word-%26-word
```

and

```
#word-&amp;-word
#word-%26amp;-word
#word-%20amp%3B-word
```

However, both versions are not working.

What would be the appropriat way to fix this?

Comment: Jekyll supports [multiple different Markdown implementations](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/markdown/) and each uses its own method for converting headings to slugs. Which Markdown implementation are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Kramdown is striping non alphanumeric from header id's and replacing spaces by `-`.

You can just check this behavior with :

```
- mandatory
{:toc}

### word & word
```

Resulting link in generated table of content is `#word--word`

See [kramdown documentation](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc)

Comment: I tried this and it gives me a list with links to all my headings exept for the one I am looking for. The one I am looking for is displayed without a link.